# 0.19 kg apple falling (a problem on Work and Power)

Tags: energy, work

### Problem

A 0.19-kg apple falls from a branch 3.5 m above the ground.

- a) Does the power delivered to the apple by gravity increase, decrease, or stay the same during the time the apple falls to the ground? Explain. Find the power delivered by gravity to the apple when the apple is
- b)2.5 m and
- c)1.5 m above the ground.
  *(James S. Walker Physics (4th edition) problem 71 page 214)*

---

### Solution 1

$$
\triangle y=v_{0}t+\frac{at^{2}}{2}=-\frac{gt^{2}}{2}
$$
$$
t=\sqrt{-\frac{2\triangle y}{g}}=\sqrt{\frac{2d}{g}}
$$
$$
P=\frac{W}{t}=\frac{Fd}{t}=\frac{mgd}{\sqrt{\frac{2d}{g}}}=\frac{m\sqrt{g^{3}}\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
so for *d=1* I get P=4.13W and for *d=2* I get P=5.84W

---

### Solution 2

$$
v^{2}=v_{0}^{2}+2a\triangle y=-2g\triangle y=2gd
$$
$$
v=\sqrt{2gd}
$$
$$
P=Fv=mg\sqrt{2gd}=m\sqrt{2g^{3}d}
$$
for d=1 I get P=8.26W and for d=2 I get P=11.68W

---

There is also one more thing I've found on the Internet that uses [kinetic energy](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Physics-1358/2011/3/Pysics.htm) to get the same results as solution 1. But the answer of the problem in the book is 8.2 and 12.

### Question

So the question is why solution 1 is wrong? Why do I get two different results? Can someone explain please?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

Power = $\vec F \cdot \vec v = Fv$ if $\vec F$ and $\vec v$ are in the same direction.  In this case the power at a given time is instantaneous force $\times$  instantaneous velocity.

In the first case you are finding the average power which you will note is equal to half the final instantaneous power which is second case value.

Comment: It dosent get more correct than this.